# VSCode debugging Go, call stack only show one function

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I use vscode to debug Go program. 
But the call stack only show current break point function, no backtrace info.
I use dlv command or goland, the backtrace info is right. 
Where is the config error?

- vscode only one function:
  [image]

my workspace and configure

- vscode go:
  [image]
- launch.json:
  [image]
- user settings:
  [image]

Comment: [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: package main

func test() {
 var a int
 a = 10
 print(a)
}

func main() {
 test()
}

Comment: I'm having this same issue on a large project, and I created a simple main that calls a single function and it reproduces there as well. Windows 7, windows 10, vscode latest, latest go 1.11.4, or go 1.11.1.